# MVC3 - Getting Service Layer to Work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am trying to get a basic service layer working in my application, but I'm running into trouble.

Interface:

```
public interface IEmailer
    {
        string ServiceTest();
    }
```

Service:

```
public class SimpleMailer : IEmailer
    {
    public string ServiceTest()
        {
            var ServiceVar = "This is your service working";
            return ServiceVar;
        }
    }
```

Controller:

```
    public class EmailSendController : Controller
    {

    private IEmailer _service;

     public EmailSendController()
        {
            _service = new SimpleMailer();

        }

        public EmailSendController(IEmailer service)
        {
            _service = service;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit()
        {

            _service.ServiceTest();

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting an error that `_service.ServiceTest();` is null.  What am I doing wrong that's preventing it from returning `ServiceVar`?

Comment: What is the Error message you see ?

Comment: +  $exception {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."} System.Exception {System.NullReferenceException}

Comment: Your code works for me.  I get `_service.ServiceTest()` returning the string "This is your service working"  I tested using both controller constructors.

Comment: I am using Ninject for Dependency Injection, could this be part of my issue?  DO I not have it bound correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on what controller constructor is being hit.  If you are hitting the constructor that takes an IEmailer parameter then you'll need to have a way of creating the SimpleMailer concrete class to supply to the constructor.  A typical way of having this controller created with that instance is to use dependency injection.  I'm assuming it's attempting to create the controller with that constructor because of the null reference exception that happened.

Could you please post your mapping code for Ninject along with your Global.asax.cs code so we can see exactly how your implementing your Ninject container?  It's hard to pin point what the issue could be without seeing the code.

Not only do you have to set up a container in the Application_start but you'll also need an IDependencyResolver implementation for Ninject which should be available via NuGet if you look.  That's how your controller's will be able to look up their parameter's concrete implementations in order to create the controller.

Comment: I am currently using Ninject for dependency injection.  Here is my bind code: kernel.Bind<IEmailer>().To<SimpleMailer>();  Is that not correct?

Comment: I've only worked with StructureMap and Unity before.  Put a breakpoint in your constructor and see if the parameter in that constructor has been supplied with a SimpleMailer object.  I'm guessing it's null b/c your container isn't setup correctly.  Could you show your ninject container code?

Comment: @user547794 Take a look at [link](http://www.shahnawazk.com/2010/12/dependency-injection-in-aspnet-mvc-3.html)

Comment: Hmm..  For some reason it's not even hitting my controller constructor.  Why would that be?

Comment: Well it has to be hitting either one of those constructors.  Are you sure you have debugging enabled in your application's web.config?

Comment: Doh!  I had another Controller Constructor that was there by mistake.  Now it's working.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have the following in your `NinjectWebCommon.cs` -> `RegisterServices()` (or in `global.asax` -> `CreateKernel()` if you use it that way):

```
kernel.Bind<IEmailer>().To<SimpleMailer>().InRequestScope();
```

Also, remove your parameterless constructor (or 'rem' it out for now) in order to test that this is working via Ninject, otherwise the parameterised ctor will never be hit.

**[Edit]** just noticed, you have no `HttpGet` action method in your code, therefore I'd suggest you change the signature of the `HttpPost` action to `HttpGet`, otherwise, you have no way of invoking a get request from anything that exists in your controller at present.

Comment: It looks like neither of the constructors were being hit.  I did remove the paramaterless constructor and received the same error.

Comment: a quick question before i unfortunately have to duck out, have you tried making the Edit action a `HttpGet` and invoking it from the address bar. as the code stands, I can't see anyway that you are able to test this as there's no `HttpGet` action method